# Validation Error when printing tables with PHP

Tags: php, html

I get a validation error while printing the following table in php.

```
echo "<table class = '1'>";
        echo "<tr><th>Fahrenheit</th><th>Celsius</th></tr>";
        if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $message == '') {
            for ($i = $min; $i < $max; $i += $step) {
                $temp = ($i - 32) / 1.8;
                $temp = round($temp, 2);
                echo "<tr><td>" . $i . "</td><td>" . $temp . "</td></tr>";
            }if ($i > 1) {
                echo "You are viewing temperature conversion from $min to $max incrementing by       $step <br><br>";
            }
        }echo "</table>";
```

The table does print and works fine, but it does not pass validation and I get the following error.

The border attribute on the table element is obsolete. Use CSS instead.

From line 48, column 13; to line 48, column 32

```
      <table border = '1'><tr><t
```

Comment: line number 48 refers to which line of this code?

Comment: This is a large file I took the piece where I had an error. But I found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
echo "<table class = '1'>";
```

try to use

```
echo"<table class = 'table'>"; and format it using CSS.

 table,td {   border: 2px solid gray;   
         border-collapse: collapse; }
```